# Can't Create High Definition Render Pipeline Asset in Unity (Create > Rendering Doesn't Exist)

Tags: unity, shaders

I've upgraded my project to Unity version 2019.3.0a11. It complains and can't load scripts, mostly because it can't seem to load the original HDRPipeline. I want to make graphics display properly.

In Unity's instructions, they say to [go to Assets > Create > Rendering and click High Definition Render Pipeline Asset](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@6.9/manual/HDRP-Asset.html) and create this in the `Assets` folder. Problem is, Assets > Create > *Rendering* doesn't exist.

[image: adding HDRP no menu item]

- I'm in Assets/Settings
- I upgraded the High Definition RP, Post Processing, and Core RP Packages
- Restarted Unity many times
- Searched for a suitable asset

Here is what the package manager says:

[image: package manager hdrp]

There is an exception thrown in Unity about `Shader error in HDRP/Lit: failed to open source file: 'Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.core/ShaderLibrary/Version.hlsl' at /…/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@7.0.0/Runtime/ShaderLibrary/ShaderVariables.hlsl …`

In fact, there is a whole wall of exceptions:

[image: exceptions for HDRP]

Comment: What does your package manager say about the HDRP Package?

Comment: @DMGregory I added a picture so you can see exactly.

Comment: Have you tried removing and re-adding the package? What specific script errors are you getting?

Comment: @DMGregory I did try removing and re-adding the packages many times (both Core RP and High Definition RP). For the script errors, they are above.

Comment: have you tried reimport all assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution has been to completely remove all packages in the Package Manager that were awaiting download. Then, I removed High Definition RP and the Core RP Library. After restarting, I added the High Definition RP package back (minus the Core RP Library), and the menu item appeared.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded my project into 2019.2.6 version from 5.2.1 & my game play graphics didn't display properly. I used Cleared Baked Data in the lighting setting as shown below:

[image: Lighting Setting]

After that, my game play graphics display properly.